# CSS button/link not registering on some clicks

Tags: css, button, hyperlink, click

I want a button to "depress" when clicked. However, the method I have attempted has an undesirable effect - some clicks in certain locations on the button aren't being registered.

**This question is not about JavaScript.** I have linked to a JSFiddle below, which uses a JavaScript click event listener, but this is only to describe the problem better. The actual problem I'm facing is nothing todo with event listeners - the hyperlink itself does not work when clicked in various places (the browser doesn't navigate to the linked page, and even though the CSS `:active` class works fine, the browser behaves as if there wasn't even a click).

> [image: Fat button] The fat, depressable button I'm trying to style.

CSS I'm using:

```
a.fatButton {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 16px;
    background: #faa;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 0 0 #f88;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
a.fatButton:active {
    top: 8px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

HTML of button inside container div:

```
<div id="linkContainer">
    <a class="fatButton" href="#">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle describing the problem in more depth: http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/d3Y9X/

And here is a recording of the problem: http://youtu.be/N6UfWdbA1Ac

The problem is when there is any movement in the button... this could be a change of the "top" property - as in this example - a margin-top, a negative margin-bottom, a translateY, padding-top ... there must be a way to create this type of button-press effect without having this problem?

I am using Chrome 29, which was used to record the video, but the problem is also apparent in Firefox 23, although the "dud area" is in a different place on the button within Firefox.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use the mousedown event instead? I found that to work fiddle: jsfiddle.net/d3Y9X/6

Comment: @cjross The JavaScript in the JSFiddle was only added to show the problem - in fact, the problem I'm having is that the link doesn't actually follow through to the hyperlinked page when clicked (ignoring JavaScript altogether). I added the click event listener just so it was more apparent to what was going wrong here.

Comment: could you please update your question with the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are moving the button with the :active selector. The top of the element changes by 8px and this happens before the click event is registered with Javascript. So when you click within the top 8 pixels the click won't register.

You could achieve the same effect by also changing the padding-top value within :active.

```
a.fatButton:active {
    top:8px;
    padding-top:16px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NT5e2/

Comment: Your fiddle performs exactly as mine did - adding padding-top does not change anything.

Comment: Also, it isn't just the top of the button that is unresponsive - look at the Youtube video, it doesn't register clicks at about 1/3 and 2/3 of the height of the button.

Answer (score 1):

i think we can use "mousedown" instead of "click" , can solve this problem

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3Y9X/8/

```
document.querySelector("a.fatButton").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    c++;
    csp.textContent = c;
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question literally, but I can't accept it as answering my actual problem. I've made an edit to my original question: while mousedown is a workaround when dealing with JavaScript events, my _actual_ problem is that the link itself doesn't work as a hyperlink - the JavaScript in the fiddle was just added as an easier way to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that the `:active` pseudo-class is used to apply css to elements while they're being clicked upon. So it happens before click event triggers. When you move the button position `8px` down, the button is not there any more and it has been moved to `8px` down so the click event does not trigger and the link does not work.

`Solution:`
I think you should design a background image with shadow and another one without shadow and toggle the background image of your button when it is being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

it seems position issue remove position:relative it will work
new code...

```
a.fatButton {
    display: inline-block;

    margin: 8px;
    padding: 16px;
    background: #faa;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 0 0 #f88;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
a.fatButton:active {
    top: 8px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
<div id="linkContainer">
    <a class="fatButton" href="#">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work correctly. When you remove the `position` property, the button does not move down when it is being clicked. By default position is `static`. In order to apply `top` property position should be `relative`

Answer (score 0):

If you move an element like that (in your case, with top or padding values) the "mousedown" event remains, but you are changing the area in which that press will trigger the "click" DOM event.

Maybe this would help:

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/123-if-it-moves-when-you-click-make-something-stick/